# ALSA Hooks -- Modifying audio as it's being played

Tags: audio, hook, alsa

I'm at a loss with this — I have several personal projects in mind that essentially require that I "tap" into the audio stream: read the audio data, do some processing and modify the audio data before it is finally sent to the audio device.

One example of these personal projects is a software-based active crossover.  If I have an audio device with 6 channels (i.e., 3 left + 3 right), then I can read the data, apply a LP filter (×2 – left + right), a BP filter, and a HP filter and output the streams through each of the six channels.

Notice that I know how to write a player application that does this — instead, I would want to do this so that any audio from any source (audio players, video players, youtube or any other source of audio being played by the web browser, etc.) is subject to this processing.

I've seen some of the examples (e.g., pcm_min.c from the alsa-project web site, play and record examples in the Linux Journal article by Jeff Tranter from Sep 2004) but I don't seem to have enough information to do something like what I describe above.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a job for an [external filter plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___ext_plug.html). (For examples, see the `upmix` or `vdownmix` plugins.)

Comment: Am I understanding this right?  From the docs in http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_external_plugins.html: "The filter-type plugin is a plugin to convert the PCM signals from the input and feeds to the output".  This is not what I'm after --- I want to intercept data being sent to the output (from totem or VLC video players; from youtube or in general from the web browser; from games, etc.), modify it (including changing number of channels, etc.) and let it continue its way to the output device.  Am I misunderstanding? Can I achieve this with external filter plugins?

Comment: This is exactly what a filter plugin does; "input" and "output" do not refer to separate devices but to the flow of data.

Comment: Huh --- the phrasing in the doc is really weird; looking at the first two lines, one might be convinced that they're talking about input device and output device. Oh well; I'll keep trying with their examples and the pcm_upmix.c code and see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your project as a LADSPA plugin, test it with `audacity` or any other program supporting LADSPA plugins, and when you like it, insert it into alsa/pulseaudio/jack playback chain.

"LADSPA" is a [single header file](http://ladspa.org/ladspa_sdk/ladspa.h.txt) defining a simple interface to write audio processing plugins. Each plugin has its input/output/control ports and `run()` function. The `run()` function is executed for each block of samples to do actual audio processing — apply "control" arguments to "input" buffers and write result to "output" buffers.

Example LADSPA stereo amplifier plugin (single control argument: "Amplification factor", two input ports, two output ports):

```
///gcc -shared -o /full/path/to/plugindir/amp_example.so amp_example.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ladspa.h"

enum PORTS {
  PORT_CAMP,
  PORT_INPUT1,
  PORT_INPUT2,
  PORT_OUTPUT1,
  PORT_OUTPUT2
};

typedef struct {
  LADSPA_Data *c_amp;
  LADSPA_Data *i_audio1;
  LADSPA_Data *i_audio2;
  LADSPA_Data *o_audio1;
  LADSPA_Data *o_audio2;
} MyAmpData;

static LADSPA_Handle myamp_instantiate(const LADSPA_Descriptor *Descriptor, unsigned long SampleRate)
{
  MyAmpData *data = (MyAmpData*)malloc(sizeof(MyAmpData));
  data->c_amp = NULL;
  data->i_audio1 = NULL;
  data->i_audio2 = NULL;
  data->o_audio1 = NULL;
  data->o_audio2 = NULL;
  return data;
}

static void myamp_connect_port(LADSPA_Handle Instance, unsigned long Port, LADSPA_Data *DataLocation)
{
  MyAmpData *data = (MyAmpData*)Instance;
  switch (Port)
  {
    case PORT_CAMP:    data->c_amp    = DataLocation; break;
    case PORT_INPUT1:  data->i_audio1 = DataLocation; break;
    case PORT_INPUT2:  data->i_audio2 = DataLocation; break;
    case PORT_OUTPUT1: data->o_audio1 = DataLocation; break;
    case PORT_OUTPUT2: data->o_audio2 = DataLocation; break;
  }
}

static void myamp_run(LADSPA_Handle Instance, unsigned long SampleCount)
{
  MyAmpData *data = (MyAmpData*)Instance;
  double amp = *data->c_amp;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < SampleCount; i++)
  {
    data->o_audio1[i] = data->i_audio1[i]*amp;
    data->o_audio2[i] = data->i_audio2[i]*amp;
  }
}

static void myamp_cleanup(LADSPA_Handle Instance)
{
  MyAmpData *data = (MyAmpData*)Instance;
  free(data);
}

static LADSPA_Descriptor myampDescriptor = {
  .UniqueID = 123, // for public release see http://ladspa.org/ladspa_sdk/unique_ids.html
  .Label = "amp_example",
  .Name = "My Amplify Plugin",
  .Maker = "alsauser",
  .Copyright = "WTFPL",
  .PortCount = 5,
  .PortDescriptors = (LADSPA_PortDescriptor[]){
    LADSPA_PORT_INPUT | LADSPA_PORT_CONTROL,
    LADSPA_PORT_INPUT | LADSPA_PORT_AUDIO,
    LADSPA_PORT_INPUT | LADSPA_PORT_AUDIO,
    LADSPA_PORT_OUTPUT | LADSPA_PORT_AUDIO,
    LADSPA_PORT_OUTPUT | LADSPA_PORT_AUDIO
  },
  .PortNames = (const char * const[]){
    "Amplification factor",
    "Input left",
    "Input right",
    "Output left",
    "Output right"
  },
  .PortRangeHints = (LADSPA_PortRangeHint[]){
    { /* PORT_CAMP */
      LADSPA_HINT_BOUNDED_BELOW | LADSPA_HINT_BOUNDED_ABOVE | LADSPA_HINT_DEFAULT_1,
      0, /* LowerBound*/
      10 /* UpperBound */
    },
    {0, 0, 0}, /* PORT_INPUT1 */
    {0, 0, 0}, /* PORT_INPUT2 */
    {0, 0, 0}, /* PORT_OUTPUT1 */
    {0, 0, 0}  /* PORT_OUTPUT2 */
  },
  .instantiate = myamp_instantiate,
  //.activate = myamp_activate,
  .connect_port = myamp_connect_port,
  .run = myamp_run,
  //.deactivate = myamp_deactivate,
  .cleanup = myamp_cleanup
};

// NULL-terminated list of plugins in this library
const LADSPA_Descriptor *ladspa_descriptor(unsigned long Index)
{
  if (Index == 0)
    return &myampDescriptor;
  else
    return NULL;
}
```

(if you prefer "short" 40-lines version see https://pastebin.com/unCnjYfD)

Add as many input/output channels as you need, implement your code in myamp_run() function. Build the plugin and set LADSPA_PATH environment variable to the directory where you've built it, so that other apps could find it:

```
export LADSPA_PATH=/usr/lib/ladspa:/full/path/to/plugindir
```

Test it in `audacity` or any other program supporting LADSPA plugins. To test it in terminal you can use `applyplugin` tool from "ladspa-sdk" package:

```
applyplugin input.wav output.wav /full/path/to/plugindir/amp_example.so amp_example 2
```

And if you like the result insert it into your default playback chain. For plain alsa you can use a config like (won't work for pulse/jack):

```
# ~/.asoundrc
pcm.myamp {
  type plug
  slave.pcm {
    type ladspa
    path "/usr/lib/ladspa" # required but ignored as `filename` is set
    slave.pcm "sysdefault"
    playback_plugins [{
      filename "/full/path/to/plugindir/amp_example.so"
      label "amp_example"
      input.controls [ 2.0 ] # Amplification=2
    }]
  }
}
# to test it:   aplay -Dmyamp input.wav

# to point "default" pcm to it uncomment next line:
#pcm.!default "myamp"
```

See also:

- [ladspa.h](http://ladspa.org/ladspa_sdk/ladspa.h.txt) - answers to most technical questions are there in comments
- [LADSPA SDK overview](http://ladspa.org/ladspa_sdk/overview.html)
- `listplugins` and `analyseplugin` tools from "ladspa-sdk" package
- [alsa plugins : "type ladspa" syntax](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html), and [alsa configuration file syntax](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/conf.html)
- [ladspa plugins usage examples](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Ladspa_%28plugin%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your hands dirty with some code, you could check out [some of these articles](http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html) by Paul Davis (Paul Davis is a Linux audio guru). You'll have to combine the playback and capture examples to get live audio. Give it a shot, and if you have problems you can post a code-specific problem on SO.

Once you get the live audio working, you can implement an [LP filter](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Definition_Simplest_Low_Pass.html) and go from there.

There are plenty of LADSPA and LV2 audio plugins that implement LP, HP and BP filters but I'm not sure if any are available for your particular channel configuration. It sounds like you want to roll your own anyway.

Comment: Yes, the digital filters part is the easy one for me... Once upon a time, when the Pentium II roamed the earth and the C/C++ Users Journal still existed, I created this (arguably neat) C++ FIR filters library and published the article in the C/C++UJ --- I have my own copy here, in case anyone is curious: https://mochima.com/articles/FIR/FIR.html

Comment: @Cal-linux oh, that's pretty cool. Are you going to use a DSP library for your filter?

Comment: When I get to that point I will decide what works well and is easy --- again, having experience with DSP, that is the part that is not causing me any stress :-)  With today's PC's, performance should not be an issue (I know, I know --- famous last words? :-) )